# Which is faster, saving to a 2D list or CSV for millions of data?

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have over 20 million lines of data, each line with 60-200 int elements. My present method of using:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for block in reading_file(f):
        for line in block:                         
            a = line.split(" ")
            op_on_data(a)
```

where `reading_file()` is a function that takes around 1000 lines at a time. And `op_on_data()` is a function where I do some basic operations:

```
def op_on_data(a):
    if a[0] == "keyw":
        print 'keyw: ', a[0], a[1]
    else:
        # some_operations on arr[]
        for v in arr[splicing_here]:              
           if v > 100:
               # more_operations here
               two_d_list(particular_list_location).append(v)
        for e in arr[splicing_here]:
           if e < -100:
               two_d_list_2(particular_list_location).append(e)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

And in the end I save the `two_d_list` to a Pandas Dataframe in ONE move. I do not save in chunks. For around 40,000 lines of a test dataset I got an initial time of `~10.5 s`. But when I do the whole dataset, my system crashes after a few million lines. Probably because the list gets too large.

I need to know what is the best way to save the data after doing the operations. Do I keep using lists or save directly to a CSV file inside the function itself like line by line? How do I improve the speed *and* prevent system from crashing?

Edit: I am open to other options apart from lists and CSV.

Comment: Are the two options you mention your only options (i.e. are you looking for a comparison between these and nothing else), or are you open to other options such as numpy.save(), HDF5 files, etc.?  If you haven't considered any other options, then take a look here to see if any might be suitable: https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/storing-binary-data-and-serializing/

Comment: I am open to other options as well. But at these two I am more or less competent in. Numpy also seems like a good idea. Thanks for the link, I will check it out.

Comment: For things that go beyond the memory limits, you could use `dask`, and save to either `hdf` or `feather` [dask docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_parquet)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make the code more efficient and generator based.
I see too many for loops for no good reason.

If anyhow you are iterating through lines so begin with this

```
for line in open("file.txt"):  # open here is a generator (avoid using your own read functions)
    a = line.split(" ")
    op_on_data(a)
```

And for the second code snippet, here are more code review comments for the below code:

```
def op_on_data(a):
    if a[0] == "keyw":
        print 'keyw: ', a[0], a[1]    # Avoid printing when iterating million of lines !!!
    else:
        # some_operations on arr[]
        for v in arr[splicing_here]:  
           if v > 100:
               # more_operations here
               two_d_list(particular_list_location).append(v)
        for e in arr[splicing_here]:
           if e < -100:
               two_d_list_2(particular_list_location).append(e)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

**CODE REVIEW COMMENTS:**

1. Do not iterate big arrays simply with for loop, always use generators/iterators, e.g.:

   ```
       from itertools import cycle
       my_iter_arr = cycle(arr)
       for v in my_iter_arr:
           # do something
   ```
2. Try to combine the 2 for loops into 1. I cannot see the reason why you are using 2 for loops, try:

   ```
   for v in my_iter_arr: 
        if v > 100:
            two_d_list(particular_list_location).append(v)
        elif v < -100:
            two_d_list_2(particular_list_location).append(v)
   ```
3. And the worst is appending millions of elements into an array stored in RAM, avoid the `two_d_list(particular_list_location).append(v)`, I am not sure how two_d_list is efficiant! instead try to see when list reaches a sum of X elements dump the elements to a file! and continue appending to a clean list!

Try reading about Python Generators / Lazy iteration

Comment: I am going to try the reviews out and post results. Can you recommend though, where to dump the list when it reaches said sum of X elements? Like is dumping to a CSV file faster for 5000 elements than say .txt or .dat for line by line?

Comment: Why would the file suffix matter? dump/append the chunks in any file opened by python - the file name/ending should not effect the spee nor the program efficiancy.

Comment: I expressed it wrong perhaps, I meant saving 5000 elements in one go vs. every element individually to a file thereby removing the need for the lists. Which would be faster?

Comment: Saving a chunk of elements will be the better approach (5000 sounds nice). Writting each line to a file will produce a high level of I/O calls which will slow down the process dramatically.